# how to forbid ultrasurf

Tags: kerio

I blocked related port number but kerio still fails to forbid ultrasurf. Is there anyone solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the last pages

http://www.astaro.org/astaro-gateway-products/web-security-http-https-ftp-im-p2p-web-filtering-antivirus/20319-ultra-surf-8-8-how-block-4.html

They say that they blocked it.

(I hope that linking to other sites it's not a violation :p)

Answer (score 0):

Blocking of port 9666 will not help - this is localhost port only. You have to monitor connections to port 443. There is Brazilian Linux script for blacklisting ultrasurf servers using iptstate (can't find it at the moment) - but in my case it was enough just to block packets to destination network 65.49.0.0/18 with destination port 443.

Here is another way to block -

[Article from Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/most-detailed-way-block-ultrasurf) is on using hash to prevent ultrasurf application from running.

[Another article](http://jonsnetwork.com/2009/01/blocking-ultrasurf-with-a-sonicwall-application-firewall/) on blocking based on object footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Palo Alto firewalls, they inspect the payload, not the header of packets to determine application and filter on that. I like how they pull in the need for separate devices into your edge.